# WebClient.DownloadData hangs

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I am trying to download file using WebClient.DownloadData. Usually the download is Ok, but for some Urls the download just hangs.

I've tried to override the WebClient, and set a timeout to the WebRequest, and it didn't help.

I've also tried to create WebRequest (with time out), then get the WebResponse, and then get the stream. When I've read the stream, It hangs again.

This is an example for a url that hangs: http://www.daikodo.com/genki-back/back-img/10genki-2.jpg.

Any Idea?

Comment: When you set a time out is it timing out?

Comment: No. That is my problem. My process just hangs until I kill it.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the slow downloads using either Fiddler or Wireshark to see what's happening? e.g. is it just consistently slow all the way through or is it quite fast then just stops for some reason. Alternatively maybe enabling network tracing may shed some light? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx

Comment: Can you post your downloading code?  From the look of the responses so far it would seem that the problem is more likely to be your connection than your code, but if we can see your code it'll help confirm that.

Comment: The regular using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) wc.DownloadData(url);

I've also tried to inherit WebClient and add timeout in the GetWebRequest overrided method

Comment: Is this happening on the very *first* web request or do you have to make a bunch of them before running into the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use to download files from multiple servers. Note that I have set a limit to how much I want to read from the response stream because in the event I get a file exceeding the specified size, I don't want to read all of it. In my application, no URL's should result in a file exceeding the size; you may omit this limitation or increase this amount as needed.

```
int MaxBytes = 8912; // set as needed for the max size file you expect to download
string uri = "http://your.url.here/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Timeout = 5000; // milliseconds, adjust as needed
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000; // milliseconds, adjust as needed
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // Process the stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        string tempString = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0 && sb.Length < MaxBytes);

        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will solve the hanging problem you are having, but it works well for my app.

Comment: As I said in my quesion, I've tried this, and I get the same results. The file I am downloading is ~512K, and It is taking for about 40 minutes to download.

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe your own problem since my app does not hang. Here is my code sample. Could you post your code here?

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string url = @"http://www.daikodo.com/genki-back/back-img/10genki-2.jpg";
string savePath = @"C:\Temp\test.jpg";

Console.WriteLine("Downloading from: " + url);
byte[] result = client.DownloadData(url);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, result);

Console.WriteLine("Download is done! It has been saved to: " + savePath);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How long does it takes to download the data?
I've tested it, and I see that it is downloading the data, but it is taking for about 40 minutes. Using the browser It takes less then a second

Comment: it only took me a few seconds to download the image in my end.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with long delays in my downloads, for me it was because i added a check to see if the uri was valid. if someone runs into the same problem check your other web requests like URI checking.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)